# Is there a "DataTable" with "named row" in C#?

Tags: c#

I need a data structure with both named column and row. For example:

```
magic_data_table:

        col_foo col_bar
row_foo    1       3 
row_bar    2       4
```

I need to be able to access elements like `magic_data_table["row_foo", "col_bar"]` (which will give me `3`)

I also need to be able to add new columns like:

```
magic_data_table.Columns.Add("col_new");
magic_data_table["row_foo", "col_new"] = 5;
```

AFAIK, DataTable only has named column...

EDIT:
I don't need to change the name of a column or a row. However, I may need to insert new *rows* into the middle of the table.

Comment: Have a column for the names, then *index* that column - a Dictionary-string-DataRow should work fine

Comment: The question implies that the data will always have the same rows, is that right? An `IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object>>` would seem to work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could use a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, T>>` to do what you want, that wouldn't be particularly efficient in terms of memory, and would have the potential for the inner dictionaries to get out of sync.  If you create your own data structure though that is a facade for lists, using dictionaries to map column names to indexes, then it's simple enough:

```
public class MyDataStructure<T>//TODO come up with better name
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> columns;
    private Dictionary<string, int> rows;
    private List<List<T>> data;

    public MyDataStructure(
            IEnumerable<string> rows,
            IEnumerable<string> columns)
    {
        this.columns = columns.Select((name, index) => new { name, index })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.index);

        this.rows = rows.Select((name, index) => new { name, index })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.index);

        initData();
    }

    private void initData()
    {
        data = new List<List<T>>(rows.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new List<T>(columns.Count));
            for (int j = 0; j < columns.Count; j++)
            {
                data[i].Add(default(T));
            }
        }
    }

    public T this[string row, string column]
    {
        //TODO error checking for invalid row/column values
        get
        {
            return data[rows[row]][columns[column]];
        }
        set
        {
            data[rows[row]][columns[column]] = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddColumn(string column)
    {
        columns.Add(column, columns.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            data[i].Add(default(T));
        }
    }

    public void AddRow(string row)
    {
        rows.Add(row, rows.Count);
        var list = new List<T>(columns.Count);
        data.Add(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(default(T));
        }
    }

    public bool RenameRow(string oldRow, string newRow)
    {
        if (rows.ContainsKey(oldRow) && !rows.ContainsKey(newRow))
        {
            this.Add(newRow, rows[oldRow]);
            this.Remove(oldRow);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that if you were willing to fix the rows/columns upon construction then you'd be able to use a `T[,]` as the backing for the data, which would both make the class dramatically simpler to implement, and further reduce the memory overhead, although that doesn't appear to work for your use cases.

Comment: So is the idea here merely encapsulation?  Because, if there's no way to change the number of rows or columns, or change a row or column name, then the dictionaries are more or less immutable anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have added methods for adding rows/columns.  To change a column name would be simple enough if the OP wanted to add it.  The difference in memory is that there isn't a dictionary for each row, it stores the data in lists, and those lists don't require as much extra storage as a dictionary would to store the same number of values.  The reason you need to use encapsulation here is that the lists are indexed by an `int`, so you need to do the conversion from string to int.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I guess its a question of how far you want to take it. Its not entirely clear. Does the OP need to change the names of existing columns?

Comment: Since OP is not clear on the details, I think this is the best answer that can be provided right now.

Comment: apologies if I've broken etiquette.

Comment: @Jodrell Meh, apparently the OP doesn't need it, but it doesn't hurt anything for it to be there.

Answer (score 3):

Add a column for the name - "name" in the following:

```
DataTable table = ...
DataColumn nameCol = table.Columns["name"];
var index = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .ToDictionary(row => (string)row[nameCol]);

... // then when you need the values:

string rowName = ..., colName = ...
var val = index[rowName][colName];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the Tuple (.net 4.0 and above) class suits your needs. It won't work strictly like a table but will give you a lot of flexibility.

You can use the List<> generic to store it and LINQ to query your data.

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int>> magicTable = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();

magicTable.AddRange(new Tuple<string, string, int>[] {
    Tuple.Create("row_foo", "col_foo", 1),
    Tuple.Create("row_foo", "col_bar", 2),
    Tuple.Create("row_bar", "col_foo", 3),
    Tuple.Create("row_bar", "col_bar", 4)});

magicTable.Add(Tuple.Create("row_foo", "col_new", 5));

int value = magicTable.Single(tuple => (tuple.Item1 == "row_foo" && tuple.Item2 == "col_new")).Item3;
```

It is going to be quite resource intensive due to the duplication of row/column names but you do get a lot of flexibility for small datasets.

Microsoft's Tuple documenation (3-tuple): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150.aspx

Comment: The performance of this will be atrocious.  It would be a *lot* better to use a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, T>` as the data structure.  Even there, it would probably be best to create a new type to wrap it as the methods to access it aren't as simple as would be ideal.  That particular solution would be great if the data was sparsely populated, but it's not.  It's densely populated, based on what I can see of the OP's content.  Given that, a solution such as what I demonstrated would be somewhat less memory intensive and slightly faster.

Comment: I agree totally. It's not a fast solution which is why I had to add the resource comment. It does give a lot of flexibility and still keep things, from a coding side, relatively simple.